# NSTextField draw programmatically to a view

Tags: macos

I have this view called `scrollView`. It's a `NSScrollView` type. I want to draw in a text manually without using the interface builder.

I made a `NSTextField` and set the string value inside it to "Hello World," so how do I add it to the `scrollView`?

Here's the basic structure of what I am trying to do:

```
NSTextField *usernameText = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
[usernameText setStringValue:username];

NSView *subView = [[NSView alloc] init];
[subView addSubview:usernameText];

[scrollView addSubview:subView ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is classified in ios but based on the context and "NS" I'm going to go with the mac version.

You should look at Apple's "Text System User Interface Layer Programming Guide" Specifically the section titled putting an NSTextView object in an NSScrollView [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/TextInScrollView.html).

Basically you first set up the NSScrollView. Then you create and configure the NSTextView to go in the NSScrollView finally you combine the pieces.